# how do you reference a dataset from a different assembly/library in RDLC?

Tags: c#, dataset, rdlc

im rendering locally, i placed the dataset into the dataaccess tier of my solution. how can I access it from RDLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not sure how to answer your question directly, I ran into the same problem myself and here was my solution:

In C# I just acessed the report locally and overrid the datasource with whatever data I wanted to provide:

```
    using (var report = new LocalReport())
    {
        report.ReportPath = @"C:\Sample.rdlc";
        report.DataSources.Clear();
        report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyDataSet", yourDataSet));
        var bytes = report.Render("PDF");
    }
```

Then in the XML of the RDLC file, I just specified a dummy data source and then manually set the values of my own dataset:

```
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="Dummy">
      <DataSourceReference>Dummy</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:DataSourceID>bd7d6037-aff5-4ce5-a156-a75f8c1e660b</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="MyDataSet">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Name">
          <DataField>Name</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Amount">
          <DataField>Amount</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>Dummy</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText />
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
```

This has worked great for me.